# Double mouse-click event for RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList with several ListItems. As user click before thinking they select an option even if they don't need it here.

Is it possible to set the SelectedIndex of a RadioButtonList to -1 by double-clicking on the list with the mouse?

asp.net c# webapplication

Comment: Do you want that once user click on radio button, he can undo the selection ?

Comment: @bemused i dynamically create the Rbls and have several rbls on one form. i could combine a dropdown where the user selects which rbl needs to be cleared,  but if a double click is possible that would be an easier way to do it.

Comment: @muhammad Actually i want to undo the selection on click so that there is no further action needed by the user

Comment: so you want when you select some value from dropdownlist, then you want that user will no longer select the radiobutton from list?

Comment: i just said that this could be a possibility on reaction from bemused posts. if it is easier in another way i would prefer this way, like a double click on the rbl

Comment: Usually, a radio button means you HAVE to choose an option, so I really don't see the point of allowing the user to deselect everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following jquery script will uncheck the selected radio button item when double clicking on it.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">            
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').dblclick(function () {
            $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:radio:checked').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
        });
    });          
</script>
```

You might also want to consider using [MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox of Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx)